# Count the number of heads per set in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

First of all, thank you for all your responces. I am doing my best to keep up with all the suggestions. However I'm trying to stay on track.

So now I have

```
s = Table[RandomChoice[{Heads, Tails}, 2 i + 1], {i, 10}];
```

Next, I want to count the number of "Heads" that occur for each "i".

I can do this for one case....say 5,

```
n = RandomChoice[{Heads, Tails}, 5];
n1 = Count[n, Heads];
```

But I am having trouble expanding this....

Thanks again.

p.s. what are down votes? Too easy?

Comment: Down votes? There are no down votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map (`/@`) the function of counting heads in a list:

```
Count[#, Heads]&
```

to each sublist in `s`. Hence:

```
Count[#, Heads]& /@ s
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a simulation of coin flips, I believe that `BinomialDistribution` is what you want.

```
Histogram[
  Count[#, "Heads"] & /@
    Table[RandomChoice[{"Heads", "Tails"}, 9], {25000}]
]
```

[image]

```
BarChart@Table[PDF[BinomialDistribution[9, 1/2], k], {k, 0, 9}]
```

[image]

By the way, the symbol `Heads` is a built-in function and should probably not be used the way you are using it.

Comment: It's based of a Monte Carlo lecture.

Comment: @Corshot Ah, that explains some things.