# How do I count a List of Lists?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Thanks again everyone, I can't believe how far this has come. Almost there.

How do I extend the Length function.

i.e.

I can count  `{1,3}` by `Length[{1,3}]`

*2*

But how do I count the length of each set in the list `{{1,3}, {1,1,3}, ...}`?

Comment: I don't know anything about mathematica, so leaving this as a comment, but it seems to me that you simply need to iterate over the list and use a variable to hold the sum of the length of each element.

Comment: @Ed S. In Mathematica, iteration is a last resource, and usually comes with big performance penalties. It's more natural to use list-wide operations.

Comment: At this point I think you should be able to answer this one yourself, based on this reply you received: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524293/count-the-number-of-heads-per-set-in-mathematica/5524334#5524334

Comment: You asked: "How do I count a list of lists?" and "How do I extend the length function?"  If you think about it, your question really is: "How do I apply a function to the parts of an expression?" (http://reference.wolfram.com/teachersedition/MathematicaBook/26.4.html)

Answer (score 6):

Just try

```
 Length /@ {{1},{1,2,3}}
```

Which is an abbreviation of:

```
 Map[Length, {{1},{1,2,3}}]
```

`Map` applies a function (in this case `Length[]`)element-wise over lists.